# Execute default PHP function or custom function as param in function

Tags: php

I wrote a simple function that accepts two params: a string and a function.

I want that function return a value if the function passed from user with the given string is true, but how can I do this with PHP default functions passed as param?

For example, if I use

```
call_user_func( 'empty', 'test' );
```

It doesn't works, but with custom functions yes (obviously).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: [Notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-notes): "Because [`empty()`] is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions."

Comment: Oh, well. So if I want to use empty I MUST write a function returning empty() (so boolean)?

Comment: You can't write such a function, because if the variable doesn't exist then it will throw a Notice, whereas `empty` has special handling to simply return `false`.

Comment: I was thinking to something about this: function isEmpty( $str) { return empty( $str ); }  and use this as function

Comment: Sure, but what if `$str` does not exist? For a string, you'd be better off calling `strlen` and seeing if its result is 0, or even passing `function(string $str) {return $str === "";}` (assuming PHP7, which you probably aren't using :p)

Comment: Nop, I'm not using that version ahah. Btw, neither strlen I can pass as function?